# Warning: warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleProcessor' less than -source '1.8'

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-architecture-components

Trying to build a sample using Android Studio 3 Canary 5 with Architecture Components and Kotlin gives this warning.

Can anyone tell me the reason?

Thanks, Ove

Edit #1:
This is a sample made some time ago by Dan Lew

https://github.com/dlew/android-architecture-counter-sample

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.danlew.counter"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:${rootProject.archLifecycleVersion}"
    compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:${rootProject.archRoomVersion}"
    compile "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:${rootProject.archRoomVersion}"
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:${rootProject.archLifecycleVersion}"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:${rootProject.archRoomVersion}"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    String butterKnifeVersion = '8.5.1'
    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterKnifeVersion"
    kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterKnifeVersion"

    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'

    String daggerVersion = '2.10'
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"

    String rxBindingVersion = '2.0.0'
    compile "com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:$rxBindingVersion"
    compile "com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding-kotlin:$rxBindingVersion"

    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'

    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay2:rxrelay:2.0.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Please post you `build.gradle` file

Comment: have you tried to set the Kotlin  `Target JVM version` in the Kotlin settings panel to 1.8?

Comment: Setting the `Target JVM version` in the Kotlin settings has no effect on this warning.

Comment: were you able to solve this? having the same issue!

Comment: Haven't gotten down to try again... Which release are you using? Canary 7?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is a Java 8 annotation processor now arch components are stable so replace:

```
"android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:${rootProject.archLifecycleVersion}"
```

with

```
"android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.0.0"
```

Comment: @rekire Which string do you use for room?

Comment: For Room use `implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'`. [Link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html)

Comment: `android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.0` is a bit annoying as `support:appcompat-v7` has a dependency on it, meaning it's brought in  anyway.

Answer (score 19):

Just adding this answer for future reference: the same issue was also raised with the Android Arch Components team a while ago and the [official answer](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/35) for now is:

> (...) it is just a warning. Should not be a problem.

This applies to warnings following the format mentioned in the title of the question, and include:

> w: warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
>   w:
>
> w: warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'android.arch.persistence.room.RoomProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
>   w:

Basically it's `javac` informing you that these annotation processors were compiled against and generate code for a different (older) version of Java (Java 7) than your module's source level is set to (Java 8). The reason for this is that the compiler cannot make any promises that the processors will then still behave correctly [but the developers can and did in this particular case].

Note that the warning is still issued if you remove the `-Xlint` compiler flag, so short of using `-nowarn` it cannot be suppressed unfortunately.

Comment: @CoolMind: That issue was already linked to in the first sentence of this answer (see: "official answer"). ;)